# Why doesn't Serverfault have "Review" like Stackoverflow?

Tags: feature-request, questions

I've seen that Stackoverflow has a new feature which is "Reviews" to see rookies questions like mines.

Why doesn't Serverfault have that same link? Or is it a matter of privileges?

Comment: Try http://serverfault.com/review

Comment: Ah, yes, another new feature that has been clearly announced on the blog and on that "updates" question on meta.SO that's so easy to find. </snark>

Answer (score 3):

At 2k (so I've been told) you can access some of the pages in the review section and there is a Review link next to your user name at the top of the page.. At 10k you can see all the pages in the review section, but you have to go through Tools to get to Review.

Comment: I suspect like a few things they only make it easy to find once you have a certain amount of rep. I could use http://serverfault.com/review before I got to 10k

Comment: I have a link on the front page

Answer (score 1):

We do.  You just can't see it yet.  The threshold is probably 2k, but I could be wrong on that one.

Answer (score 1):

After a quick check of all the sites I'm on, I have a review link today:
[image]

This link appears on every site I have an account, on both the main and meta sites.

Across all the stack overflow sites, my total rep is over 13k, so it is possible the links are:

1.In error.

2.Suddenly available for everyone. *Happy New May!*

3.Based on total rep everywhere.

3.14159 Always there, but I only noticed today.

Comment: review link is available at 200 rep